# Decode (byte data) in request.files in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I know that if file is encode in utf-8 it must decode on same format and same for ascii

I tried but it just giving byte data not raw data.

as I know `request.files` give `encode('utf-8')` format data if I am not wrong so.
I just decode the `read()` file with `first_file.decode('utf-8')` but error and I also check `first_file.decode('ascii')` but aslo got error.
at last I just convert byte format which I got from `request.files.getlist()` to base64 and decode this base64 in default utf-8 format it work but got base64 data. so how I decode file to get data without `( b )` sign??

```
from flask import Flask, render_templates
import base64

app  = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get_me" , methods=["POST"])
def get_files():
 if request.method == "POST":
     data =   request.files.getlis("docx_files"):
     first_file = data[0].read() # read but in bytes form like b"hello"
     #decode = first_file.decode()# by default uft-8  --- got error on utf 8 and ascii  
     encoded = base64.b64encode(first_file)# convert to base64
     print("-----encoded---", encoded)
     dec = encoded.decode()# it decode byte but format is base64
     return render_templates("home.html, data=dec)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Error messages:

```
on --- first_file.decode('utf-8') <br>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 14: invalid start byte

on --- first_file.decode('ascii')<br>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

```
    <div class="container">
<form action="/get_me" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">

   <label for="formFile" class="form-label text-secondary "><strong>Upload Job Description docx File</strong></label><br>
  <input type="file" class= "form-control btn btn-outline-secondary" name="job_descr_csv" multiple=""> <br><br>
  
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" value="Submit">
    
    
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Files in '.docx' format are stored as binary data. It is a zip archive with XML documents inside.
You can open the zip archive and read and process its XML files. This example shows you how to display the XML files as text.

```
import io
import zipfile

file = '<your-docx-file>'
with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as zf:
    for fname in zf.namelist():
        print(f'-- {fname}:')
        with zf.open(fname, 'r') as fh:
            with io.TextIOWrapper(fh) as f:
                print(f.read())
```

However, this process is very extensive for reading in documents. If you only want to extract the text of the document, I recommend using [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```
import docx

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files.getlist('docx_files')
        for file in files:
            doc = docx.Document(file)
            text = '\n'.join(p.text for p in doc.paragraphs)
            print(text)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Maybe a plain text file is enough to meet your requirements. However, keep in mind that files that have been uploaded will be opened as binary files. You can open the content in text mode with a `TextIOWrapper` as shown in the first example.
I hope I was able to give you a rough overview and wish you every success in the implementation of your project.